# Active object set, object mode set, but still "RuntimeError: Error: Modifiers cannot be applied in edit mode"?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I'm trying to apply my modifier to object with Python. I've set the object of interest as the active object and ensured its mode to be object. However, I still receive this error.

Here's the relevant code.

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Subsurf', apply_as='DATA')

RuntimeError: Error: Modifiers cannot be applied in edit mode
```

I saved the .blend file right before the error and opened this file in GUI. Then, I ran

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Subsurf', apply_as='DATA')
```

that used to cause errors in the command pane, and weirdly it ran without errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the object of interest, `obj`, is indeed in object mode, but there was one object, which was neither active nor selected, in edit mode. When I made all objects be in object mode, the error was gone.

```
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = o
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    o.select = False
obj.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Subsurf', apply_as='DATA')
```

Could someone confirm if this is a bug in Blender? Two reasons:

1. I don't see why other objects are required to be also in object mode for us to apply modifiers to the object of interest.
2. GUI behavior doesn't match commandline behaviors.